# What does "ORA-24344: success with compilation" error mean?

Tags: plsql

I am very new to pl/sql blocks.

When I run the below code it shows:

> ORA-24344: success with compilation error

After executing the code it shows nothing as output

```
--Program definition: Create a procedure which will display the employees
--in descending order of employee name of the computer department

create or replace procedure proc_1(this_name in varchar2(50)) as
begin
loop
select name  from enployee2 order by name desc;
commit;
select name into this_name;
end loop;
end;



variable k varchar2(50)
execute proc_1(:k);
```

Comment: The error message means that the procedure was created (the 'success' part) but it failed to compile (the 'error' part). You now have a procedure in an invalid state.  Sometimes that is OK, if the compilation errors will be resolved by some other changes you are making and the procedure will be fine at the end. In this case it's not (see Sentinel's answer for details).

Answer (score 3):

Ok You've got lots going on here:

```
1> create or replace procedure proc_1(this_name in varchar2(50)) as
2> begin
3> loop
4> select name  from enployee2 order by name desc;
5> commit;
6> select name into this_name;
7> end loop;
8> end;
```

- On line 1 of your procedure you declare this_name as an IN parameter of type varchar2(50).  However with procedure specs you don't specify the size of the parameters. so you can drop the (50) from the spec.
- On line 4 you have select statement with no INTO clauses.
- On line 5 you have a commit, but you haven't done any work in the procedure that warrants a commit;
- On line 6 you attempt to select name into this_name, but your query has no from clause.  In Oracle SQL a SELECT without a FROM is not accepted.
- On line 6 your INTO clause attempts to store a value in the this_name parameter, but that was declared as an IN parameter not an OUT or IN OUT parameter.
- On lines 3 and 7 you open and close a loop, but you have no exit condition so the loop is infinite.

Comment: thnx, a lot sir !!